# Swift: if is let redundancy

Tags: swift

I just joined a project that has a lot of existing code. The previous programmer was perhaps unfamiliar with Swift or began development in the early stages of the Swift language. They seemed to be using the `if let` statement in an odd way. They seemed to want to use the statement as a `if is let`. Before I edit the code I would like to know if there is any valid use for this:

```
// In JSON parser

if value is String, let string = value as? String {
       document.createdBy = string
}
```

First checking if value is of type `String` seems redundant to me. Doesn't Swift check for this in the `let string = value as? String` portion of the statement?

**QUESTION**

Why would this need to be checked twice? Or would there be a reason for this?

Comment: You're right. It's just dumb. Don't imitate it. (By the way, there is no "optional chaining" in your question.)

Comment: I can't see a situation where you would need to do that. If a variable is a `String`, you don't need to cast it with `as? String` so if the variable is a `String`, the right condition is redundant. If it is not a `String` (and therefore you would want to cast it), the left condition returns false so the cast never occurs.

Comment: @matt you are right. I just didn't know what else to call that in my title that would get the point across. I updated my title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, this is redundant. If `value` is not a string, then `value as? String` would return `nil`, and the conditional binding would fail.

To check the type, and not use the casted result:

```
if value is String {
    // Do something that doesn't require `value` as a string
}
```

To check the type and use the result:

```
if let value = value as? String { // The new name can shadow the old name
       document.createdBy = value
}
```

Doing both makes no sense.